drive.permissions.create error - too many parameters
I have the following code as part of a larger script:
Drive.Permissions.create({
  "fileId": "1RynzJ-j76TIi3XIHSQeHE6XPfBdp",
  "sendNotificationEmail": false,
  "resource": {
   "role": "viewer", 
   "type": "user",
   "emailAddress": "somebodiesemail@icloud.com"
   }
});

When executed it fails with the error:
Exception: Invalid number of arguments provided. Expected 2-3 only
setFolderPermissions    @ Code.gs:87
As far as I can tell I'm only passing three parameters: fileID, sendNotificationEmail and resource albeit with resource being an object.
I've looked at the references and all the parameters used are referred to. The script is bound to a Sheet and I've 'Drive' identified as the service - is this correct/ If not how do you enable an 'advanced drive api' - I can't decide whether that is different from drive service and if so how to enable it.
I've tried using the reference example to create the code and the 'create()' block is fundamentally the same. If the construct was incorrect I'd expect a different error, but stating that it has an invalid number of arguments suggest the syntax is somehow incorrect.
I'd be grateful for any advice
Following Boris' answer I modified my code to that shown below, which included adding supportAllDrives and useDomainAdminAccess. Regardless of what I try or whether I use the ID of a file or a folder, it always stops with an error and states 'file not found'.  I can set the permission in Drive and I'm the manager of the folder as I'm a superadmin.


 Drive.Permissions.create({
   role: "reader",
   type: "user",
   emailAddress: userGoogleAccount
    },
    instrumentGroups[nCounter].FolderID,
    {
    sendNotificationEmail: false,
    supportAllDrives: true,
    useDomainAdminAccess: true                
});




Welcome to Stack Overflow. If after getting an answer you still need help, you should post a follow-up question as a new question, not as an edit of the already answered question.

Regarding revision 1 of this question, when asking for help fixing the code, please include a [mcve] (mcve). In cases like this (a Google Apps Script project bounded to a spreadsheet), you should include a complete function declaration and the relevant steps to make it work, like enabling the Drive Advanced Service. As currently there are two versions, you should specify which version was set in your "mcve".

with regard to your second point. the request to create an MCVE is unhelpful when i don't even know what is going wrong.  You ask for a complete function declaration and the relevant steps to making it work - probably if I knew how to do that I wouldn't have a problem.   PS, I've assisted on MrExcel on many occasions so I'm very aware of the benefits of presenting as representative a question as possible.  For info, it matters only a little whether I use V2 or V3 (insert/create, value/emailAddress) and in either case the result is the same.

Wicket - I see you've deleted text from my message - you've now removed the information that I wanted to pass to Boris to let him know what I've done.  How am I supposed to update those assisting me if I cant add further information?  A comment doesn't provide sufficient information and I'm not answering my own question - or is that where it should go?

I'm sorry you are having difficulties understanding how this site works. This site was created almost 16 years ago to be different from most community-driven content sites available at that time. While many other sites allow users to post nearly anything as a "question," this site has unique rules for questions. It's designed to avoid having discussions; it's not a help / service desk. Sidenote: there is an "experiment" / "beta" / "Labs" about having discussions; see https://stackoverflow.com/beta/discussions. Once you earn some reputation, you will earn privileges to access [meta] and [chat].

If you found Boris's answer helpful, I think that it's fair that you accept their answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Regarding why I rolled back the question earlier, this was because you have taken what was said to you in an answer, but you have trouble with that. As I mentioned earlier, what you should do on this site is post a follow-up question instead of editing it. This has been explained many times on [meta].

The structure is a little different as well the specified permission role is invalid. Valid values are 'reader', 'commenter', 'writer', 'fileOrganizer', 'organizer', and 'owner'.
It works:
function DrivePermissionsCreate() {
  Drive.Permissions.create({
    role: "reader",
    type: "user",
    emailAddress: "somebodiesemail@icloud.com"
  },
    "1RynzJ-j76TIi3XIHSQeHE6XPfBdp",
    {
      sendNotificationEmail: false
    });
}

You need to enable Drive API.

Hi Boris. I've tried to implement your solution, but no matter what I do it always reports an error 'File not found'.  I've tried folder ID, file ID, confirmed that the IDs are correct and that I can set both file and folder permission directly in Drive.  I've added more detail at the end of my original question.  Really appreciate your help.

Have you enabled Drive API?

Yes, and checked that its V3.  At least I think I have - it shows 'Drive' under Services in the IDE.  I am wondering if I need to 're-authorise', but don't really know what that means in this context.

I see that in your modified code the ID is calculated. Maybe there's a mistake here. Try replacing it with an absolute value, as in the original version.

Hi Boris, I've tried using both file and folder absolute versions - both with the same response 'file not found' and then it shows the submitted ID.

Then perhaps you have copied my code inaccurately. Use copy-paste. Create a new spreadsheet, copy its ID, paste it into the code, and run it.

I copied and pasted your code.  Then I created this spreadsheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12hlRAHgigeJYxy5sM08iidCyKlbNzfOvpqOq4g2nun8/edit#gid=0 and copied "12hlRAHgigeJYxy5sM08iidCyKlbNzfOvpqOq4g2nun8" into your code in place of the "1RynzJ-j76TIi3XIHSQeHE6XPfBdp".  When I ran it, it failed again: GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.permissions.create failed with error: File not found: 12hlRAHgigeJYxy5sM08iidCyKlbNzfOvpqOq4g2nun8.  Sorry this is a difficult read, but apparently i'm not allowed to add additional information to the original post.

No access to the file.

Peter, make yourself a copy of this spreadsheet. I slightly modified the code in it. Now you don't need to enter your ID manually. The script automatically inserts the ID of the active spreassheet. Enter the required EMAIL and run the script.

That worked.  But using the same script with different IDs - again for files or folders failed with file not found.  This makes me think that because its a bound script it doesn't have access to those other files or folders and so can't use this particular call to grant permissions, whereas addViewer() works successfully.  Does that make sense?

"But using the same script with different IDs - again for files or folders failed with file not found" - I can't repeat this. When I use the ID of my other spreadsheet, the script also works well. I tested the script on other objects in my Google Drive (folder, jpg file) - it also works well.

Your problem may be that the object ID is incorrect. Try checking it programmatically, for example, getting the object name using its ID.

Hi Boris, the larger script does just that by getting the folder and then its ID.  I'm using it on a shared drive - let me try it on my Google Drive and see if makes a difference.
